# Using React Native with post-robot

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, cross-domain, post-robot

My webpage communicates between its windows and Iframes using post-robot cross domain post-messaging service (https://github.com/krakenjs/post-robot).

I want to display this webpage in my React Native Webview and capture and send events using post-robot. Any suggestions on this

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?