# Why is window.location undefined in React Native?

Tags: react-native, window.location, post-robot

I'm trying to use [post-robot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/post-robot) to communicate with a [React Native WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview). It's failing because post-robot is trying to access `window.location.href`. While `window` [is defined as a global](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Core/setUpGlobals.js#L20) in React Native, it's missing `location`.

This looks like it's intentional, rather than a bug. If it is intentional, is there a reason for this?

Whether intentional or not, the best path forward isn't clear to me. I haven't found any other libraries like post-robot that do have React Native support.

Edit:

After digging a little more, I found another SO post from someone trying to use post-robot with React Native. There are no responses, and they don't mention if they ran into the same issue with `window.location` that I am: [Using React Native with post-robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008606/using-react-native-with-post-robot)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't make sense in React Native. ```location``` of what?

Comment: That's true, there's not actually a `location`, but neither is there actually a `window`. The RN devs polyfilled it as a global for compatibility with JS libraries that expect `window` to be there. I suppose my question boils down to "if window is polyfilled, why not location?"

Comment: ```setInterval```, ```addEventListener``` ... are there. But ask yourself ... how could you even polyfill ```location```? What would it look like? There is no location in React Native